# Convert powerpoint to pdf,or to image in DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5 for c#(winrt)

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I writing app about open file powerpoint in winrt(tablet).
i using c#, visual 2015.
i researched but not found component support it.
I would like to embed file powerpoint to my app or convert powerpoint to pdf,image

you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenXML file format is open by definition. You can create your own implementation that fit your needs (Full support might not be required).

Or you can use a third party library to save time.

Aspose : http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx

e-Iceblue : http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/presentation-for-net-introduce.html

My recommandation would be to create a secured web service to convert the documents from .ppt/.pptx to .pdf.

Comment: I this answers your question, feel free to put the green check ;)